# What's the best centralized syslog viewing tool for *nix out there

Tags: web, syslog

Looking for what people think are the best for doing web viewing of a centralized syslog server. I am open to using any syslog server also.

**EDIT**

I actually went with [GrayLog2](http://www.graylog2.org/)

Comment: splunk maybe need more characters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using [Loganalyzer](http://loganalyzer.adiscon.com/) with rsyslog, and it seems to work ok. The web frontend's a bit clunky, but does the job.

Answer (score 7):

I like Splunk myself, not cheap though.

Answer (score 2):

Not tried it, but **logstash** sounds like it will do what you want:

http://code.google.com/p/logstash/

The license is New BSD.

Comment: Logstash is also nice in combination with Graylog2. Logstash to collect and prepare events and logs, and Graylog2 to search through the collected logs. Logwatch can now be found at http://logstash.net/